# Handle class options in the order they're given

Tags: package-writing, options, package-options

How can I pass options of my package in a specific order to another loaded package?

```
\ProvidesPackage{L10n}
\DeclareOption{english}{\PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{babel}}
\DeclareOption{ngerman}{\PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{babel}}
\DeclareOption{others}{% other options are also declared}
\DeclareOption*{\OptionNotUsed}
\ProcessOptions
\usepackage{babel}
```

Above declaration results in babel being loaded with `english,ngerman` always regardless whether I load `L10n` with

```
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{L10n}
```

or

```
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{L10n}
```

How can I manage to have the options `ngerman` and `english` in order for babel when loading my package?

Comment: I tried to specify your title a bit, hope you don't mind. The previous wording hinted at a question way simpler than yours actually is.

Comment: `\ProcessOptions*` is what's needed.

Comment: `\ProcessOptions*` scans through all options. I only want to pass english and ngerman to babel but in the given order. There are other options not being passed to babel but handled by my package. I don't know the way how to handle options differently when using `\ProcessOptions*`

Comment: @egreg or Sebastian: Please post this as an answer. I would do it myself you where first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It mostly depends on what the other options should do. The command

```
\ProcessOptions*
```

will scan the option code in the order the options are passed to the package, without doing anything for the options not specified at package call. If other options do things that shouldn't depend on the calling order, then you have a problem.

In general it's not a good idea to call **babel** from a package, as this cuts out languages which are not provided in the package as an explicitly declared option.

A clean way might be to load options with a key-value interface, so

```
\usepackage[languages={ngerman,english}]{L10n}
```

could do the job by passing the languages to babel in the prescribed order and maintaining the possibility to choose any supported language. Many packages use this syntax.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds good but sadly I got stuck
`\DeclareOption{languages}{\PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{babel}}`
Doesn't work now. I need to handle the key-value pair correctly.

Comment: @Sebastian: you should look the documentation of package **kvoptions**