# What is the proper way to implement language options in a multilanguage package?

Tags: babel, package-options

I'm writing a multilingual LaTeX2e package to be used with pdflatex containing several macro and environment definitions. The main language of the document--a thesis--is English, Finnish or Swedish. One page of the document contains text in one secondary language, again English, Finnish or Swedish. My problem is in some ways similar to the one [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28540/handle-class-options-in-the-order-theyre-given).

I have implemented the choice of the main language as an option of my package, which I then pass on to the `babel` package using `\PassOptionsToPackage`. I then process the package options with `english` as the default. However, specifying a language other than `english` globally as say `\documentclass[finnish]{article}` doesn't seem to pass on the chosen language to `babel` while `\usepackage[finnish]{mypackage}` does. This is evident from the caption in tables and figures, which are in English and not Finnish, as well as the title of the list of references, which is also in English in the first case.

After digging around I found a solution to my problem (a more elegant one to using flags and then loading `babel` with the appropriate options) [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111958/new-class-base-on-book-class-with-options?rq=1).

My question is why doesn't `\PassOptionsToPackage` pass on the option to `babel` when it is specified in `\documentclass`? The option isn't passed on when `finnish` is specified to both `\documentclass` and `\usepackage{mypackage}` either. Why? A minimum working package code for `mypackage.sty` is:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypackage}[2013/09/26 Version 0.01]

\DeclareOption{english}{%
  \PassOptionsToPackage{english}{babel}
%  \AtEndOfClass{\main@language{english}}
}
\DeclareOption{finnish}{%
  \PassOptionsToPackage{finnish}{babel}%
%  \AtEndOfClass{\main@language{finnish}}
}
\DeclareOption{swedish}{%
  \PassOptionsToPackage{swedish}{babel}%
  %\AtEndOfClass{\main@language{swedish}
}
\ExecuteOptions{english}% Default package options
\ProcessOptions \relax

\RequirePackage{babel}%
\RequirePackage[latin1]{inputenc}%
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}%

\endinput
```

A not-so-minimal LaTeX file that shows the caption and reference list heading in the wrong language follows:

```
% This works when \AtEndOfClass{\main@language{...} is uncommented
% but not with \PassOptionsToPackage{finnish}{babel}.
\documentclass[finnish]{article}
\usepackage{mypackage}

% This works with \PassOptionsToPackage{finnish}{babel} uncommented.
% This causes an error with \AtEndOfClass{\main@language{
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[finnish]{mypackage}

\begin{document}

\section{Johdanto}

Tämän tekstin lähteenä oleva tiedosto on opinnäytteen pohja...

\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{\label{taulukko1} Taulukon kirjaintyypin...}
\vspace{1em}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|l|r|}
\hline \textbf{A} & 1 & $e^{j \omega t}$ \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\subsection*{Lähdeluettelo} 

Viite \cite{bcs} on esimerkki artikkelin esittämisestä lähdeluettelossa.

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{bcs} Bardeen,\ J., Cooper,\ L.\ N. ja Schrieffer,\ J.\ R.
  Theory of Superconductivity. \textit{Physical Review,} 1957, vol.      108, nro~5, s.\ 1175--1204.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Doesn't the `babel` key `main` solve it? -- ie, pass `main=finnish` instead of just `finnish`.

Comment: If you want to use this also with Babel 3.8, then the only ways are: (1) avoid executing the `english` option, or (2) passing the language options to `mypackage` rather than the class. With Babel 3.9 you can use `main=<language>` in `\DeclareOption{<language>}`

Comment: The global option *is* passed, but before the local options, among which there is `english`. So `english` ends up to be the last one.

Comment: Adding `main=finnish` works, but it generates the warning Unused global option(s): [main=finnish]

Comment: What I meant was to pass it with `\PassOptionToPackage`. Due to way LaTeX handles options, a global option cannot be the main language if other languages are set as package options.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is why doesn't `\PassOptionsToPackage` pass on the option to
>   babel when it is specified in `\documentclass`?

The thinking was that there was no need to as it was a global option so the included package already sees it. Of course babel is a bit special as it matters there about the order or the options, the last one being default, that isn't really handled in the general code.

Comment: Shouldn't a global option, `finnish` here, be passed to to `babel` loaded by `mypackage` regardless of whether it is an option of `mypackage`?

Comment: What puzzles me even more is that when I load `babel` with the option `finnish` as `\RequirePackage[finnish]{babel} in the above package with `\PassOptionsToPackage` active, Finnish isn't activated. Why is this so?