# \@ifpackagewith doesn't behave as I expected with global options

Tags: babel, package-options, class-options

When I compile the following code, I expect a "Yes" but I get a "No" instead. Is there something subtle going on or is my method for checking wrong? If so, how can I see which options have been passed to `babel`? (It's for a class I'm writing.)

`\@ifpackageloaded{babel}` gives a "Yes", as does `\usepackage[english]{babel}`.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\newcommand{\control}{undefined}
\makeatletter
    \@ifpackagewith{babel}{english}
        {\renewcommand{\control}{Yes}}
        {\renewcommand{\control}{No}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\control
\end{document}
```

Comment: You aren't loading `babel` with the `english` option. `;-)` Indeed, global options don't appear in the list associated to `babel`.

Comment: @egreg Yes but why? Shouldn't global options be passed to every package, babel included?

Comment: They are passed, but the macro `\opt@babel.sty` isn't updated with the global options: it only contains the “local” options.

Comment: @egreg Is this a subtlety of babel only? I mean, should I always repeat the relevant options when I call babel, even if I declared them in the class too?

Comment: No, it's for all packages.

Comment: @egreg ["The global option is passed, but before the local options."](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/136793/what-is-the-proper-way-to-implement-language-options-in-a-multilanguage-package#comment309343_136793) There isn't any local option (am I wrong?), so... I'm a little confused prof. :S  
(edit) I wrote this before you posted your last comment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you load a package with

```
\usepackage[a,b,c]{package}
```

the macro `\opt@package.sty` is defined to expand to `a,b,c`; such a macro is used for `\@ifpackagewith`. However, global options are not included in the list. So, if the package know the option `g` and you do

```
\documentclass[g]{article}

\usepackage[a,b,c]{package}
```

the option `g` *will* be passed to `package` before the options `a`, `b` and `c`. However the code

```
\@ifpackagewith{g}{package}{YES}{NO}
```

will follow the false branch. Unfortunate? Yes.

Can you do something about this? Of course you can, because the global options are stored in `\@classoptionslist`, but there's no explicit interface for it.

The `babel` package relies on `\date<language>` being defined as a check that the language has been loaded, either as a global or a local option.

Here's an `expl3` version of `\@ifpackagewith` that also checks the global options.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\packageoptionsTF}{mmmm}
 {
  \stanton_package_options:nnTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \stanton_package_options:nnTF
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
   {
    \clist_if_in:cnTF { opt@#1.sty } { ##1 }
     { #3 } % it's a local option
     {
      \clist_if_in:cnTF { @classoptionslist } { ##1 }
       { #3 } % it's a global option
       { #4 }
     }
   }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\control}{undefined}
\newcommand{\ita}{}

\packageoptionsTF{babel}{english}{%
  \renewcommand{\control}{Yes}%
}{%
  \renewcommand{\control}{No}%
}
\packageoptionsTF{babel}{italian}{%
  \renewcommand{\ita}{Yes}%
}{%
  \renewcommand{\ita}{No}%
}

\begin{document}

\control

\ita

\end{document}
```

The output is

> Yes
>   No

Comment: Thanks egreg. This ranks among the best pieces of code I've ever stolen from here :-)

Comment: @ArchStanton You're welcome! I have even better code on the site, notwithstanding what a fellow chat resident might say. `;-)`

Comment: egreg, I don't understand the code, but I think it only checks if the options are given but not if the package is actually loaded, judging by how it behaves.

Comment: @ArchStanton You're right: `\@ifpackagewith` doesn't balk if the package has not been actually loaded. It's the same for the code I proposed. Probably you want to add the check whether the package has been loaded.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it did.